# Physics 2 E field of charged disk/ring etc etc

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

For the problems where you're given a charge density and you integrate k dq/r^2 to find e field (y components usually cancel, etc).. Why are they always nonconducting/plastic? What happens if the disk or ring is metal/conducting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textbook excercises do that so that any charge distribution is plausible. On conductors that's not the case. In particular, since conductors have free charges on their volume, any electric field within them would cause motion of charges. Therefore in the static case any conductor must have a null electric field inside of them. By gauss' law we have $0=\epsilon_0\nabla\cdot E=q$, that is, inside a conductor there cannot be any net charge. Therefore a disk with a charge density which doesn't vanish inside (say $kr$ proportional to the distance you are from the disk) would not be possible if the disk is a conductor.